# Scheduling a task using python script

Tags: python

I am trying to schedule a task, but it is giving me the following error

```
The filename, directory name or volume label is incorrect
```

Can someone please help me fix this. I am relatively new to python. Here is my code below:

```
import os, time 
runHr = 23 #Hour of the day that you would like to run the batch file
runMin = 00 #Minute of the hour the batch file is to be run
while True:
        currTime = time.localtime ()
        if currTime.tm_hour == runHr and currTime.tm_min == nMin:
                os.system("C:\subdir\Unzip.bat ")
                time.sleep (79200)
```

Comment: You have an extra space at the end of the `system()` call. And also (even though it does not matter in this case) `\ ` is the escape character for python strings. Use `r"C:\subdir\Unzip.bat"` to disable escaping.

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy, so I can't help you with the CMD error, but but busywaiting like that is a *really* bad idea. You'll be pushing your CPU at 100% for up to 24 *hours*. Either register it with the system scheduled executer thing (don't know what that would be for Windows, the equivalent to cron), or at least use sleep between your tests as well, preferably for a long time.

Comment: It will probably be much easier to use the Windows "at" command. "at 23:00 C:\subdir\Unzip.bat"

Comment: FYI, `AT` is deprecated as of Windows 8 (possibly earlier, too). The Windows way of doing this is with Task Scheduler, which has a straightforward GUI.

Comment: Is there a typo on the if statement? Should nMin be runMin?

Comment: Thanks! It works with r"C:\subdir\Unzip.bat"